# How can I permanently increase my Dexterity ability score?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, ability-scores

Currently, I am playing a level 5 Halfling rogue with 22 dexterity. 17 base + 2 for race + 2 for gloves of dex(+2) + 1 from level up.
How can I increase my dexterity to its relative maximum using only rules in the 3.5e PHB and DMG?
Ways I know already:

- 17 points base
- 2 points from race
- 5 points from leveling
- 6 points from item
- 5 points from wishes
  Totaling 35

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**That's it.**

Other than starting from an 18 point base, that's it.  In the 3.5e PHB and DMG, that's the maximum.

**In Non-Core, however.**

The [Sources of Bonuses to Ability Scores](https://web.archive.org/web/20160913044554/http://www.minmaxboards.com/index.php?topic=176) thread at *Brilliant Gameologist's* Min/Max Boards provides all known bonuses to ability scores.

**In SRD only**

The SRD (System Reference Document) is the freely released freely available D&D content outside of web articles and the like.  It's available in handy hypertext format at [d20srd.org](http://www.d20srd.org/).

Taking a quick look through that, the Whirling Frenzy custom barbarian Rage variant gives +4 dex, the Epic Level rules have a feat that gives +dex, and the monsters included include lots of +dex races that also have a listed LA - and so are playable, if terrible.

**With the MM**

With the MM1, and the *polymorph* or *shapechange* spells, you can boost your base dex quite high, and then add the normal buffs on top of that to have a quite high dex.

It's 'permanent' because those spells can, with Extend and repeated castings, last most of the day.

Comment: I was just reading the DMG, would the +5 Manual of Quickness of Action be considered inherent bonus which is capped at +5 including wishes?

Comment: @dryver. It specifically says that it's inherent, and bonuses of the same name do not stack (unless they say they do, which inherent doesn't).

Is this a matter of scholarly interest, or are you trying to achieve something specific?

Comment: Just scholarly, and trying to make my rogue as powerful as the game and my DM lets me, within reason (not like Pun-Pun).

Comment: @dryver - Being a powerful rogue is about understanding the kind of story you are in and preparing appropriately in terms of gear, contacts, and strategy.  Not max dex score.  You will always have less raw numbers as a rogue than a spellcaster, or even a fighter-type, your strong suit is being an int-based hero, so planning.  Skills are great with planning and forethought, terrible if you try to shoot at them at a problem like a spell.  That said, google 'flask rogue', as it's probably what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Good thing my rogue is already pretty intelligent! Can polymorph be permanent?

Comment: @dryver - Ask a new question with your actual goal 'how do I make the strongest possible Rogue using these sources', specify if you just want to be 'roguelike' or actually use the rogue class, and i'll write an answer based on that.

Comment: @dryver - Polymorph Any Object can be permanent, but only between similar objects.  Or with major RAW vs RAI cheese.  The best way to utilize polymorph is nearly always to be a spellcaster.  Buffs from spellcasting can make a spellcaster a better rogue than a rogue, or a better warrior than a warrior.  The only downside is getting 'caught with your buffs down', which, since many of them are long duration, is unlikely.

Comment: *Reduce Person* grants a +2 size bonus to dexterity